# Why won't my javascript page link to my HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble linking my javascript to my HTML. I can get my CSS to link but the javascript won't? I have two javascript pages and both won't link.

Here's what I wrote in the HTML:

`<script src="js/question.js"></script>`

`<script src="js/app.js"></script>`

Comment: You might not be providing the correct path to `app.js` and `question.js`.. can you show us the error being thrown?

Comment: Also, adding the relevant code snippet would help us to help you.

Comment: @TannerDolby it's not telling me what's wrong, it's just highlighting it and not linking

Comment: @ddcastrodd I'm sorry, I am doing this for an assessment, I wasn't sure how much code to insert into the question. How much is a relevant code snippet?

Comment: Typically, this would be due to an incorrect filepath. If for example your HTML file is inside a folder which is on the same level as the `js` folder, the filepath would be `src="../js/question.js"`

Comment: I assume your running JS client-side, open up your developer tools on the .html page and navigate to the console. There should be an error message to help you fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this type of error concerns the path. Try to prepend a "/" to your path, like: `<script src="/js/question.js"></script>`